# moving a virtual mouse with touch in UWP causes flashing cursor

Tags: c#, uwp, touch

I'm attempting to emulate the behavior of Windows 10's Virtual Touchpad, ie when a user touches a control inside the app and moves their finger around, the system cursor will mirror their movement.  However, I notice that there seems to be some conflict between the system processing touch and mouse inputs simultaneously, where the touch input wants to hide the cursor, and the mouse input wants to show the cursor.

I started by building a boilerplate UWP App in VS-2019, here's my MainPage.xaml, where the only thing I'm changing is giving my Grid the *Name="Touchpad"* property so I can track pointer events within it:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Playground.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Playground"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid Background="Black" Name="Touchpad">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I'm using `Windows.UI.Input.Preview.Injection` to move the mouse cursor.  Because this is a *Restricted Capability* I made changes to my project as defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection#remarks

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private Point lastPosition;
        private InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(480, 480);
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;

            Touchpad.PointerPressed += new PointerEventHandler(Touchpad_PointerPressed);
            Touchpad.PointerReleased += new PointerEventHandler(Touchpad_PointerReleased);
            Touchpad.PointerMoved += new PointerEventHandler(Touchpad_PointerMoved);
        }

        private void Touchpad_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            PointerPoint pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(Touchpad);

            Point currentPosition = pointer.Position;

            if (pointer.PointerDevice.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Touch &&
                lastPosition != currentPosition &&
                pointer.Properties.IsPrimary == true)
            {
                Point delta = new Point(currentPosition.X - lastPosition.X, currentPosition.Y - lastPosition.Y);
                InjectedInputMouseInfo mouseInfo = new InjectedInputMouseInfo();
                mouseInfo.MouseOptions = InjectedInputMouseOptions.Move;
                mouseInfo.DeltaX = (int)delta.X;
                mouseInfo.DeltaY = (int)delta.Y;                
                if (inputInjector != null)
                {
                    inputInjector.InjectMouseInput(new[] { mouseInfo });
                }
                lastPosition = currentPosition;
            }
        }

        private void Touchpad_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            lastPosition = new Point(0,0);
        }

        private void Touchpad_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            PointerPoint pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(Touchpad);
            if (pointer.PointerDevice.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Touch &&
                pointer.Properties.IsPrimary == true)
            {
                lastPosition = pointer.Position;
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I noticed that while moving my finger around, there seems to be two cursors (or one that's bouncing back and forth really fast) - one in the app itself, and one in the system/desktop.  I added `Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = null;` which successfully hides the cursor inside the app, but the one that's being driven by the injection is blinking/flickering.

I feel like I'm missing something, as the feedback on the Virtual Touchpad in Win10 is buttery smooth and is also a UWP app, as far as I know...

Comment: I tested your code, but I could not show the cursors in my side. could you provided the complete sample for us? Could you tell more about your test device?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, I updated the question with some more comprehensive sample code.  To answer your other question, I am testing on a Surface Book 2, in Windows 1903.

Comment: Ok I got it. I will create a repro sample with your code.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT - were you ever able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Still haven't had any luck with this issue, any more insight someone could provide?